# How many (visually) different ways there are to arrange DISCRETEMATHEMATICS

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I know that visually different means that for example for the set `AABB` the 2 `A`s are treated the same so $A_1A_2B_2B_1$ is the same as $A_1A_2B_1B_2$ but i am unsure how to express this mathematically, in particular how to calculate it for more complex examples such as `DISCRETEMATHEMATICS` where there are $11$ unique letters and $19$ slots for them, i think it is something along the lines of $\frac{11!}{19!(11-19)!}$ but this gives me a negative factorial $(-8)!$.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: 19 letters in all, divide out the repetitions of each letter that repeats (n repetitions, divide by n!). Example ABBC would be $\frac {4!} {2!} = 12$

Comment: @IntegrateThis so I would be correct in saying for DISCRETEMATHEMATICS it is 19!/((6*2!)*(2*3!)

Comment: If that's the appropriate amount of each doubling and tripling, too tired to check but you get the general idea :)

Comment: you should review the definitions of combinations vs. permutations. Also there is no such thing as (-7!) lol. Permutation: the number of ways you can arrange something considering order. Combination: the number of ways you can arrange a k-subset of an n-set not considering order.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: $2!^6$, etc, really

Comment: another visual different arangement $$\begin{array}\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& S \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& C \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& I \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& T \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& A \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&& M \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&& E \\
&&&&&&&&&&&& H \\
&&&&&&&&&&& T \\
&&&&&&&&&& A \\
&&&&&&&&& M \\
&&&&&&&&  \\
&&&&&&& E \\
&&&&&& T \\
&&&&& E \\
&&&& R \\
&&& C \\
&& S \\
& I \\
D\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the letters we get

`AACCDEEEHIIMMRSSTTT`

So it should be

$$\binom{19}{2,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,2,3} = \frac{19!}{2!2!1!3!1!2!2!1!2!3!}$$

The notation on the left is the [Multinomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

First assume that all the letters are different. This gives you $19!$ different arrangements. And then start to take account that some are indifferentiable. In your case you have $2$ $A$s, in how many ways can these to be arranged? The answer is $2!$ so this has to be divided out since the exchange of $A$ and $A$ does not give rise to a new arrangement. Further you have $2$ $C$s and these can be arranged in $2!$ different ways so we have to divide this out as well. Further you have $3$ $E$s these can be arraned in $3!$ different ways, and so on. Finally you will arrive at
$$
\frac{19!}{2!2!3!2!2!2!3!}.
$$

Comment: I actually like this answer better because it explains what's going on and why this works.  I just kind of... throw notation around.